# Error Service Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I started learning Symfony recently but I can not use the services, I get this error and I do not understand why. can you help me ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKwQJ.png]

[image]

Comment: where is the service definition inside the yaml file (`services.yml`)

Comment: [Edit] your code into your post!

Comment: It looks like you have a bad indentation in your yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to correctly indent the code inside the `services.yml` file. Like:

```
services:
    isen_user.antispam:
        class: ISEN\UserBundle\Antispam\ISENAntispam
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Dan Costinel ! Thanks a lot